# how can I run multiple functions of a module in different threads?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I am working on a project called [monte carlo tree search(MCTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search). In my project, there is a main loop which is time limited. The psudo code for MCTS module goes like this:

```
import time
class mctsagent:

  def select_node(self):
    # do sth
  def expand(self):
    # do sth
  def roll_out(self):
    # do sth
  def backup(self):
    # do sth

  def search(self, time_budget):
    # main loop
    startTime = time.clock()
    num_rollouts = 0

    while (time.clock() - startTime < time_budget):
      result1 = self.select_node()
      result2 = self.expand(result1)
      result3 = self.roll_out(result2)
      self.backup(result3)
      num_rollouts += 1
```

I want to use **threads** to have as many as iterations possible.
The question is that **how can I develope a class which could make use of threading module to run the search function in different threads.**

for example develope a module like this:

```
class MCTS_Thread:
  def __init__(self, agent, time_budget):
    self.agent = agent # MCTS module
    self.time_budget = time_budget # The time for running loop
  def run(self):
    self.agent.search(self.time_budget)
```

and then **instead of search function (# main loop) I use this**:

```
def search(self, time_budget):
  threads = []
  for i in range(3):
    # 3 threads running search
    t = MCTS_Thread(self, time_budget)
    threads.append(t)

  for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
  for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

The only thing matters here is that **the functions in search function have to run in the same order in each thread**.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use threads in this case? If an ordered execution is required it makes little sense to have things 'run' concurrently, not to mention that Python threads cannot do that anyway due to the [dreaded GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) - you'll need the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module for a true parallel execution.

Comment: I want to increase the number of iterations. each iteration adds more nodes to the tree and then tree grows bigger. bigger tree results in better estimates. Each iteration could be run in a thread and then nodes could be gathered in a same tree.